# grpc service (.net5) can not be remote debugged due to missing w3wp

Tags: .net, azure, debugging, grpc, w3wp

I am getting my hands dirty with gRPC and meeting some issues debugging it as follows:

I have a Solution with multiple projects, relevant one is a .NET5 with installed packages:
[Nugets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVgPE.png)

So it even has a reference to another project(.NET Standard 2.1) where my DBContext lives, but i guess this is not relevant.

The project is pretty much the templated one and runs without any problems as far as I can see! This means I can start and debug it at my local machine.

Now I want to deploy it to my azure app service, where I saved a connection string or better said a reference to this string living in a key vault. I can deploy without problems and it runs, shows up the page with the response that is templated: *"Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909%22)*

What I can not do, but really want to do is to remote debug this project! What have I done:

- Deployed project from VS successfully
- Cloud Explorer, picked App Service, Attach Debugger and Exception:
  [A process named "w3wp" with arguments "XYWebApp" was not found. The process may still be starting. Please try again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRhBG.png)

As I said: It is running and showing up the Response after deploying and starting the app service... AND it works local!

Azure Service is configured with HTTP2, allow Remote debugging and my VS 2019 Version as IDE. After this error app service is still running. Did i miss some configuration at service side?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Might be a bug in Visual Studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/528107/unable-to-attach-remote-debugger-to-app-service-sl.html

Comment: Thank you Alex! Your hint did the trick for me, you should have posted it as an answer as HarshithaVeeramalla-MT already said. Greetings from Augsburg!

Comment: I would have posted it as an answer if I was sure that it was actually your issue ;-) Feel free to accept the posted answer, they invested a bit more time in actual research.