# .net5 Azure Web App can not be debugged properly due to disconnects

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, logging, remote-debugging, .net-5

I have a .NET5 Service running at azure. Now I try to debug and i can connect successfully after this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062549/grpc-service-net5-can-not-be-remote-debugged-due-to-missing-w3wp). So one Problem solved, next:

But for now it seems to happen randomly, that after connection the debugger disconnects from service.

So I do following:

- restart service at azure, did this many times. Also tested with stopping service and start manually again.
- immediatly press shortcut for reattach to process because i want to watch ConfigureServices method.
- it connects successfully
- shows nothing, means not ending up in any breakpoint
- May I be to slow? Do not think so and "Thread.Sleep || Task.Delay" are not helping for catching up any Breakpoint..
- after beeing connected it takes almost no time and i get this in my Output:
  [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kErW.png)
- After few Seconds I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h29vL.png)
- Within Azure Diagnostic Tools Application Event Logs I can see following [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh5T0.png) (I tried several times)
- Two entries from list are relevant as i guess, first says [RDB connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugd1Y.png), second that [application has shutdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KsHC.png)

Local debugging works fine by the way! Any suggestions where to find additional logging information or what is going on here?

I just found some additional logging in the Cloud Explorer of VS2019. in eventlog.xml I can see many events saying [debugger already connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY2XQ.png)

May be anybody can help me getting further. Otherwise I will setup a new Project in my solution, maybe i broke something, and create a new azure service to have those components clean. Thank you guys!

**Update:**
Now I created a new service at azure, Set up a new project in VS2019 and no improvement. I tried to check against a new project with View too and tried to see how far code is beeing executed by throwing exceptions and it seems to be executed with no problems through whole startup class, just the remote debugging seems not working because of remote debugger already connected.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by having 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode' enabled.
To workaround:

1. List item
2. Tools->Options
3. Go to Debugging->General
4. Scroll down to the bottom of the list and uncheck 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode'
5. Start debugging again

The *debug* attribute of the *compilation* element in your *Web.config* file must be set to "true".

```
<system.web>  
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="*.*" />  
<httpRuntime targetFramework="*.*" />  
</system.web>
```

This means, you either have to do a 'Debug' build or manually edit the ***Web.config*** file.

Be sure to add your IP Address to the firewall rules while you are debugging remotely.